# Serializing AuthenticationRequest in DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, dotnetopenauth

I've implemented an OpenID provider and an OpenID relying party, both are set in a load-balancing environment.

I've implemented the appropriate DB stores, but am now left with the dependency of `ProviderEndpoint` on the session.

I would like to somehow store the request not using the `ProviderEndpoint` but some other mechanism which doesn't rely on in-memory sessions. For example storing the request on the Cookie or in the Querystring.

The problem that I ran into is that I can not serialize the `IAuthenticationRequest` or the `IRequest`.
The underlying classes are internal, so I am also unable to cast to these.

Anyone has pointers on how to implemented this without any usage of Sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes implementing `IAuthenticationRequest` and `IRequest` are indeed `[Serializable]`.  You should be able to serialize them for shared storage across servers all you want.  The `ProviderEndpoint` control's method for persisting them is strictly for convenience for simple sites.  You don't have to use it.

For example:

```
IAuthenticationRequest request; // you obtain this from DNOA
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(ms, request);
ms.Position = 0;
request = (IAuthenticationRequest)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
```

Comment: Can you please give me a tip on how to Serialize these interfaces?
The classes themselves are internal, and so when deserializing, there is no constructor to be called.

Comment: The binary formatter does not require public classes.  I'll beef up the answer to include a sample.

Comment: This works great. The problem now is that the string that I am getting back (after base64 encoding) is to big for a cookie.
I guess the only option is to store it in some DB, right?

Comment: A database, or whatever your user session store is.